# Calculate mean and variance of a function of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, variance, means

I am working on a problem and I need to compute the mean and variance of $Y$, i.e. $E\{Y\}$ and $E\{Y^{2}\}$ is required, where
$$
Y = \frac{A^{2}+B^{2}+AB+CD}{\sqrt{(A+B)^{2}+(C+D)^{2}}},
$$
where A, B, C, and D are Normal random variables with $\mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{2})$.
First I started with the mean of $Y$. So, I first separated the terms. The first term is
$$
Y_{1} = \frac{A^{2}}{\sqrt{(A+B)^{2}+(C+D)^{2}}}=\frac{A^{2}}{\sqrt{X}}.
$$
Then, according to the 'law of total expectation', we have
$$
E\{Y_{1}\}=E\{E\{Y_{1}|A\}\}=E\{E\{\frac{A^{2}}{\sqrt{X}}|A\}\}=E\{A^{2}E\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}}|A\}\}.
$$
Is this a right way to continue, or I am totally wrong. I need your hints and help.

Comment: 5 mins. later and Mathematica is still trying to evaluate $\mathsf EY$...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you?!

Comment: Mathematica was unable to evaluate the first moment after running for 10 min. That definitely  doesn't mean the problem is impossible but it is certainly not trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I found the results.

Comment: Please post them as an answer to your question!

Comment: Sure, after publishing my paper!

Comment: find the results here: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9855413

Comment: Congratulations!  You should post an answer to your original question explaining how you got the solution.  Also consider posting a brief summary of your paper as an answer [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/papers-that-originated-on-math-se).